# Chat box scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found a solution here on Stackoverflow but I can't get it working

```
...
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="mtchat" class="chat">

    </ul>
</div>
...
```

And here the js it adds the new `<li>` but scrolling doesn't work

```
worker();

function worker() {

  // ajax request deleted

  updateChat();
  setTimeout(worker, 1000);

};

function updateChat() {

  $('#mtchat').append('<li class="right clearfix">Hallo</li>');

  var height = $('#mtchat')[0].scrollHeight;
  var dheight = $('#mtchat').height();
  var scrolling = height - dheight;
  $('#mtchat').scrollTop(scrolling);
  console.log('height:'+height);
  console.log('dheight:'+dheight);

}
```

In the console, I can see `scrollHeight` and `Height` is always the same even if the overflow starts.

I have made a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/qucenufiqa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: have you added jquery to this? i don't see it in your jsbin...that's going to put a huge damper on this code working since it requires jquery.

Comment: thank you I fixed the jsbin now.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9dqsoh3b/)

In here, `worker()` method is only been called once and this in return just sets up the stuff for us:

- Adding one "Hallo" as welcome message, only once
- Assigning the handler for `button` click
- Timer for updating the chat box

**Code :**

```
function worker() {

  $('#mtchat').append('<li class="right clearfix">Hallo</li>');
  // ajax request deleted
  setTimeout(updateChat(), 1000);
  $("#btn-chat").on("click", function(){
    var text = $('#btn-input');
    $('#mtchat').append('<li class="right clearfix">'+ text.val() +'</li>');
    text.val('');
  });
};

function updateChat() {
  var height = document.getElementById('mtchat').scrollHeight; - $('#mtchat').height(); 
  $('#mtchat').scrollTop(height);
}
```

Comment: No that's not what I want. And you jsfiddle don't autoscroll either. :( The worker is only periodically reading via ajax new updates from the chat partner. The ajax request I deleted because not necassary for demonstration purpose. My Problem is only that auto scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS Bin does not include the jquery library in the head.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Include the above within the `head` tag

Also the following line should be fixed as below:

```
var height = document.getElementById('mtchat').scrollHeight; - $('#mtchat').height();
```

to

```
var height = $('#mtchat')[0].scrollHeight - $('#mtchat').height();
```

`$('#mtchat')[0].scrollHeight` is jquery way of writing  `document.getElementById('mtchat').scrollHeight`

Since you are using jquery everywhere else.

Comment: thanks I fixe the jsbin now but auto scrolling doesn't work (even with the jquery version you suggested)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out now.
`.panel-body` was intended to `overflow` but I checked the `scrollHeight` of the `<ul>` in the `div.panel-body`.